# Can Sagan block active acts once they've been detected?

Tags: ids, logging

I'm trying to determine if [Sagan](http://sagan.quadrantsec.com/) can do anything similar to [`fail2ban`](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) where detected attacks can be temporarily blacklisted, via a system's firewall (`iptables`). Does Sagan have any "countermeasures" or "active response" capabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling I came upon this page titled: [Snortsam - A Firewall Blocking Agent for Snort](http://www.snortsam.net/) which is a plugin for [Snort](http://www.snort.org/). According to this plugins page it can integrate with Sagan as well:

*excerpt*

> SnortSam has also been integrated with Sagan, which is a log analysis
>   engine developed by Champ Clark. The Snortsam Output Plugin and
>   related files (header, Twofish) are available at the Sagan GitHub
>   repository.
>
> SnortSam itself consists of two pieces -- the output plugin within
>   Snort™ and an intelligent agent that runs on the firewall, or a host
>   near the firewall. The agent provides a variety of capabilities that
>   go beyond other automated blocking mechanisms, such as:
>
> - White-list support of IP addresses that will never be blocked.
> - Time-override list.
> - Maximum block time ceiling as well as minimum block time definition for reporting entities. Flexible, per rule blocking
>     specification,    including rule dependent blocking time interval.
> - A SID filter list of allowed or denied SIDs based on reporting entity.
> - Misuse/Attack detection engine (including roll-back support) that attempts to mitigate the risk of a self-inflicted Denial-Of-Service
>     in the IDS-Firewall integration.
> - Repetitive (same IP) block prevention with customizable window to improve performance.
> - TwoFish encrypted communication between Snort™ and the SnortSam agent.
> - True OPSEC support using the Checkpoint SDK (opsec plugin).
> - Block tracking and block expiration for firewalls that don't support timeouts.
> - Multi-threading for faster processing and simultaneous block on multiple devices.
> - File logging and email notification of events. ... and finally, using the client/server (snort/snortsam) architecture to build large, 
>     distributed response networks in a very scalable fashion.